# Append json object to json array

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I'm trying to append a json object to an existing json array with jsonlite. The json object I'm trying to append is created with `toJSON`.

For example:

```
library(jsonlite)

order1 <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
order2 <- list(a = 4, b = 5, c = 6)

# step1 represents my already existing json array
step1 <- toJSON(list(order1, order2), auto_unbox = TRUE)
# [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6}] 

# order3 is a list that I would like to append to the step1array
order3 <- list(a = 7, b = 8, c = 9)
```

I've tried:

```
step2 <- toJSON(list(fromJSON(step1), order3), auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

But unfortunately, this spits out:

```
[[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6}],{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9}]
```

Whereas my **expected result** is:

```
[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6},{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9}]
```

What am I missing?

**edit**:

I did solve this with `rbind_pages`, but it seems a bit inefficient. If there is a better solution, I'm all ears :)

```
toJSON(rbind_pages(list(fromJSON(step1), data.frame(order3))))
# [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6},{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
toJSON(rbind(fromJSON(step1), order3))
```

Result:

```
[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":4,"b":5,"c":6},{"a":7,"b":8,"c":9}]
```

`fromJSON` returns a data frame, then you should add `order3` as a new row with `rbind`. If you then convert this data frame to JSON it returns what you are looking for.

You don't have to convert `order3` from list to data frame to rbind it as a new row. There is no need to convert the data frame to a list before converting it to JSON.